# How to ignore subsequent modification of a file

Tags: git

I've a database.json, which should contain the database credential of my Zend project, I wonder if I can commit the file with sample credentials and then ignore it, to avoid other new commits...

this is the file:

```
{
    "development": {
        "resources": {
            "db": {
                "adapter": "PDO_MYSQL",
                "params": {
                    "host":     "hostname",
                    "username": "username",
                    "password": "password",
                    "dbname":   "dbname"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already tracked a file, adding it to `.gitignore` won't work - git will still track the modifications. You could use the following:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged database.json
```

You can then revert that assumption with the `--no-assume-unchanged` flag:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged database.json
```

For reference, [here's what GitHub have to say on the matter](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

Comment: It works, but your answer is incorrect, please edit it: "-unchaged" should be "-unchanged", after your correction I will accept it!

Comment: Thanks, never even spotted the typo!